# Parse some elements from a xml

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

i want to know if is possible to me to parse some atributes from a xml file, to be a object in java

I don´t wanna to create all fields that are in xml.

So, how can i do this?

For exemple below there is a xml file, and i want only the data inside the tag .

```
<emit>
<CNPJ>1109</CNPJ>
<xNome>OESTE</xNome>
<xFant>ABATEDOURO</xFant>
<enderEmit>
    <xLgr>RODOVIA</xLgr>
    <nro>S/N</nro>
    <xCpl>402</xCpl>
    <xBairro>GOMES</xBairro>
    <cMun>314</cMun>
    <xMun>MINAS</xMun>
    <UF>MG</UF>
    <CEP>35661470</CEP>
    <cPais>58</cPais>
    <xPais>Brasil</xPais>
    <fone>03</fone>
</enderEmit>
<IE>20659</IE>
<CRT>3</CRT>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JAXB to unmarshal the xml into Java object, with which you can read selective elements easily. With JAXB, the given XML can be represented in Java as follows :

enderEmit element :

```
@XmlRootElement
public class EnderEmit{
private String xLgr;
//Other elements.Here you can define properties for only those elements that you want to load
}
```

emit element (This represents your XML file):

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Emit{
private String cnpj;
private String xnom;
private EnderEmit enderEmit;
..
//Add elements that you want to load
}
```

Now by using the below lines of code, you can read your xml to an object :

```
String filePath="filePath";
File file = new File(filePath);
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Emit.class);
jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
Emit emit = (Emit) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
```

The line will give you an `emit` object for the given xml.

Answer (score 2):

For Java XML parsing where you don't have the XSD and don't want to create a complete object graph to represent the XML, [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/) is a great tool.   It allows you to easily walk the XML tree and pick the elements you are interested in.

Here's some sample code that uses JDOM to pick arbitrary values from the XML doc:

```
  // reading can be done using any of the two 'DOM' or 'SAX' parser
  // we have used saxBuilder object here
  // please note that this saxBuilder is not internal sax from jdk
  SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder();

  // obtain file object
  File file = new File("/tmp/emit.xml");

  try {
     // converted file to document object
     Document document = saxBuilder.build(file);

     //You don't need this or the ns parameters in getChild()
     //if your XML document has no namespace
     Namespace ns = Namespace.getNamespace("http://www.example.com/namespace");

     // get root node from xml.  emit in your sample doc?
     Element rootNode = document.getRootElement();

     //getChild() assumes one and only one, enderEmit element.  Use a lib and error
     //checking as needed for your document
     Element enderEmitElement = rootNode.getChild("enderEmit", ns);

     //now we get two of the child  from
     Element xCplElement = enderEmitElement.getChild("xCpl", ns);
     //should be 402 in your example
     String xCplValue = xCplElement.getText();
     System.out.println("xCpl: " + xCplValue);

     Element cMunElement = enderEmitElement.getChild("cMun", ns);
     //should be 314 in your example
     String cMunValue = cMunElement.getText();
     System.out.println("cMun: " + cMunValue);


  } catch (JDOMException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Comment: My xml that i´m testing have a namespace, and the code is getting nullpointer exception...can someone help me?

Comment: I updated my sample to show how to specify a namespace and use it when getting XMl elements.

Comment: Why i have to add namespace to my all elements?

Comment: The children all have a namespace if their parent does.

Comment: Interesting, but there is anyway to make this more simple? To don´t repeat the namespace in every children?

I found ways to replace the xmlns with a empty string...

Comment: As far as I know, if your XML document has a namespace, JDOM requires you to give it when you want any elements with that namespace.  If providing the namespace parameter for each call is problematic, and you always have the same namespace, you can wrap the getChild/getChildren call in your own method that always provides the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [StringUtils.subStringBetween](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#substringBetween%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
try

    {
        String input = "";
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILEPATH)); 
        String result = null;
        while ((input = br.readLine()) != null) // here we read the file line by line
        {
            result = StringUtils.substringBetween(input, ">", "<"); // using StringUtils.subStringBetween to get the data what you want
            if(result != null) // if the result should not be null because some of the line not having the tags
            {
                System.out.println(""+result);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            if (br != null)
            {
                br.close();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I know the code is simple, but it is usually a good idea to explain code when you post it.